# Calculate the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

A previous problem had us solving $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}$ which I calculated to be $\frac{4}{3}$ using a bit of mathematical manipulation.

Wonderful. Thank you for all the prompt responses.  Could anyone suggest an alternate technique that does not involve differentiation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your sum is equal to

$$\frac{1}{4} +\frac{2}{4^2}+\frac{3}{4^3}+\frac{4}{4^4}+ \cdots +\frac{n}{4^n}+\cdots.$$

Call this sum $S$.  Now subtract from $S$ the sum
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\cdots.$$
If we do it in the obvious way, term by term, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{2}{4^3}+\frac{3}{4^4}+ \cdots.$$

Note that this last sum is $(1/4)S$.

Putting things together, and using your computation for $1+1/4+1/4^2+\cdots$ (not quite, we start at $1/4$) we get
$$S-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{S}{4}.$$
Solve for $S$. We find that $S=4/9$.

**Comment**: The calculation is a little sloppy, it assumes that infinite sums can be manipulated much like finite sums.  There *are* theorems about power series that one could use to justify the manipulations.

But (in this case) we do not need such theorems.
Let $S_n$ be the sum of the terms up to the term $n/4^n$.  More or less the same sort of calculation as the one I did can be used to find an explicit formula for $S_n$.  Then we can calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$, and get a fully rigorous derivation.

We could use the results of the calculation of $\sum n/4^n$ to tackle $\sum n^2/4^n$, and so on.  But the derivatives approach is certainly slicker!

Answer (score 11):

As you have computed $\sum_{n>=0} x^n$ to be $1/(1-x)$, differentiate the series term-wise and multiply by x, which you can do for $x=1/4$ as the series converges. This gives $\sum_{n>=0} n x^{n} = x/(1-x)^{2}$. Substitute $x=1/4$ and observe that $\sum_{n>=0} n/4^n = 4/9$

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}x^n$. This defines a function on $(-1,1)$, equal to $\frac1{1-x}$. Using properties of power series, we know that $$\frac x{(1-x)^2}=xf'(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}nx^n$$ for the same values of $x$. Evaluating this equality at $\tfrac14$ sums your series.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can do some series manipulations... First you can write
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {n \over 4^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\,\sum_{m = 1}^n {1 \over 4^n}$$
Note that the above summation is over all $(m,n)$ with $m \leq n$. So if you switch the order of summation you obtain
$$\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\,\sum_{n = m}^{\infty} {1 \over 4^n}$$
The inner sum is a geometric series with initial term ${\displaystyle{1 \over 4^m}}$ and ratio ${\displaystyle{1 \over 4}}$, so it sums to ${\displaystyle {{1 \over 4^m} \over 1 - {1 \over 4}} = {4 \over 3}{1 \over 4^m}}$. So the overall sum is
$${4 \over 3}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} {1 \over 4^m}$$
The sum here is a geometric series that sums to ${\displaystyle{1 \over 3}}$, so your final answer is
$${4 \over 3}\times{1 \over 3} = {4 \over 9}$$

Comment: $\begin{align} 
(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \dots ) +
\\ 
(\frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \dots) + 
\\ 
(\frac{1}{4^3} + \dots ) + 
\\
\dots

\end{align}$

Comment: yeah, basically :)

Answer (score 6):

A simple probabilistic approach:

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with probability of success $p$, so that
$$
{\rm P}(X=n)=(1-p)^{n-1} p, \;\; n=1,2,3,\ldots.
$$
Then the expectation of $X$ is 
$$
{\rm E}(X) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{\rm P}(X = n)}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n(1 - p)^{n - 1} p}  = \frac{p}{{1 - p}}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n(1 - p)^n } .
$$
Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n(1 - p)^n } = \frac{{1 - p}}{p} {\rm E}(X).
$$
On the other hand, from
$$
{\rm E}(X) = p \cdot 1 + (1-p)(1+{\rm E}(X)),
$$
we get
$$
{\rm E}(X)=\frac{1}{p}.
$$
Finally,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n(1 - p)^n } = \frac{{1 - p}}{p} {\rm E}(X) = \frac{{1 - p}}{p^2}.
$$
Letting $p=3/4$ gives 
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{n}{{4^n }}}  = \frac{{1/4}}{{9/16}} = \frac{4}{9}.
$$

Comment: Nice! In imitation of the book "Proofs that Really Count", which is an attractive introduction to bijective proofs, I had thought of posting a question about **Mean Proofs**. This would ask for examples of results not in probability theory that can be proved by using the mean.  This (along with I think a few others of your posts) is a contribution to the mean proofs collection.

Comment: @user6312: Thanks. Hopefully, I'll make more contributions of this kind.

Comment: The validity of this proof actually depends on the **convergence** of $E(X)$ which of course is not difficult to prove.