# How can I calculate $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\cfrac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sum of this infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series)

How can I calculate result of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\cfrac{n}{2^n}$
 ?

Comment: similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50919/calculate-the-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-n-0-infty-fracn4n

Comment: In the same vein as the two questions cited above:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: In above links the upper limit is infinity.But here is n.

Comment: And the index of summation is $i$. This is somewhat confusing...