# deriving formula for series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can any general formula (dependent on $n$) be derived for this expression:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n 2^k k^2$$

If yes , then how we determine that any series can be converted into formula and what are ways to do that.

Comment: I am new to this group and don't know how to add characters like Sigma and all , that's why wrote this expression like that. 
Please also tell me how you write such characters .

Comment: if you edit your question, you can see what the source format looks like. You can cancel the editing if you want after your curiosity is satisfied.

Comment: @tesla You should take a look at some of the links given in the answers to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50919/calculate-the-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-n-0-infty-fracn4n.

Answer (score 5):

Start with :
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k$$
$$x f'_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k$$
$$x(x f'_n(x))'=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2x^k$$
What is $f_n(x)$?
Conclude...

---

Concerning the sentence "any series can be converted into formula". Some sophisticated methods exist but they don't work for 'any formula' (see Gosper algorithm, [Zeilberger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doron_Zeilberger) algorithm...).
A good starting point is to study [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for example in Wilf's excellent free book [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Hoping it helped,

Comment: This is the way I'd go. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I think so. (At first I thought it was $2^{-k}$, but $2^k$ will be more cumbersome.

It is the following:

$\sum_1^n 2^k + 3\sum_2^n 2^k + 5\sum_3^n 2^k+ \dots$

The summation in each case is $2\left(2^{r} - 1\right)$ where $r$ is the number of terms in the sum. The first sum has $n$ terms, second $n -1 $ and so on.

Then, you have:

$2\left[2^n + 3.2^{n-1} + 5.2^{n -2} + \dots \right] - 2\left[1 + 3 + 5 + \dots\right]$

If you were considering, $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty 2^{-k}.k^2 $, you would get a pretty neat expression. But here, the common ratio is greater than 1, so it is a bit tough.

The answer may ultimately be NO. But, now you know what to do for common ratios less than 1.